Combining PortClass driver with File I/O
I am trying to write a simple audio driver based on the PortCls framework, based on the Windows SimpleAudioSample.
What I want is to combine this with the "file-based" communication with the driver, like explained e.g. here. This uses common Windows CreateFile and WriteFile to communicate with the driver.
The issue is that the "File-based" IOCTL communication examples all directly set pointers to custom implementations of the IRP_MJ_XXX functions, e.g.:
pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE]             = Example_Close;
pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE]            = Example_Create;
pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL]    = Example_IoControl;
pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ]              = Example_ReadFunction;
pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE]             = Example_WriteFunction;

The PortCls initialisation calls in the SimpleAudioSample do a very similar thing, i.e.
ntStatus = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
                           RegistryPathName,
                           WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
                           &config,
                           WDF_NO_HANDLE);

ntStatus =  PcInitializeAdapterDriver(DriverObject,
                                      RegistryPathName,
                                      (PDRIVER_ADD_DEVICE)AddDevice);

under the hood sets exactly those IRP_MJ_CREATE, IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL, etc function pointers in the pDriverObject->MajorFunction table.
These two modes of communication therefore seem mutually exclusive. Is there a nice way to make these two work in conjunction with one another, i.e. both have a PortCls audio driver that also in some way responds to File-based IOCTL?
